# Using a Matlab Slider to update multiple plots and calculations

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab to try and investigate farfield radiation patterns of antennas.  Basically, I am trying to plot 3 different functions of x, and their fourier transform.  I have worked out how to write a script that calculates the far field of three different distributions and plots them.

However, in the script I use a variable 'a'.  I would like to be able to update the variable in real time using a slider.  When the slider is moved, a is changed, and all the calculations that use a are recalculated, and the plots refreshed.

I believe I have to change my script into a function, and use a callback.  I have been trying various things, I have managed to get a slider which updates the value of a, but it doesn't recalculate and replot.

My script is as follows.  This is my first time using matlab so it might be a bit crazy.

```
% -------  APERTURE FUNCTIONS -------

x = -5 : 0.001 : 5;  % Define the x axis
a = 1;               % Define aperture size
f1 = zeros(size(x)); % Initialise an aperture function
f2 = zeros(size(x)); % Initialise an aperture function
f3 = zeros(size(x)); % Initialise an aperture function

% Declaration of functions
for i = 1 : length(x) 
  if abs(x(i)) <= a/2
  f1(i) = 1;               % Rectangular Function
  f2(i) = cos(pi*x(i)/a);  % Cosine Function
  f3(i) = 1-2*abs(x(i))/a; % Triangular Function
  else 
  f1(i) = 0; 
  f2(i) = 0; 
  f3(i) = 0; 
  end 
end

figure;

subplot(2,3,1); plot(x,f1,'LineWidth',2); 
ylim([0 1.5]) 
xlabel('x (m)'); 
ylabel('f1(x)'); 
title('Rectangular Aperture Function');

subplot(2,3,2); plot(x,f2,'LineWidth',2); 
ylim([0 1.5]) 
xlabel('x (m)'); 
ylabel('f3(x)'); 
title('Cosine Aperture Function');

subplot(2,3,3); plot(x,f3,'LineWidth',2); 
ylim([0 1.5]) 
xlabel('x (m)'); 
ylabel('f2(x)'); 
title('Triangular Aperture Function');

%------------- FARFIELD CALCULATION ------------

u = [-4 : 0.01 : 4];  % Define the u axis
G1 = zeros(size(u));  % Initialise a Farfield function
G2 = zeros(size(u));  % Initialise a Farfield function
G3 = zeros(size(u));  % Initialise a Farfield function

for i = 1 : length(u) 
  G1(i) = trapz(x,f1.*exp(-j*2*pi*u(i)*x)); % Fourier Transform
  G2(i) = trapz(x,f2.*exp(-j*2*pi*u(i)*x)); % Fourier Transform 
  G3(i) = trapz(x,f3.*exp(-j*2*pi*u(i)*x)); % Fourier Transform 
end

subplot(2,3,4); 
plot(u,20*log(abs(G1)),'LineWidth',2);
axis([-4 4 -200 0]);
xlabel('u'); 
ylabel('|G(u)|'); 
title('Far-Field Magnitude of a Rectangular Function');

subplot(2,3,5); 
plot(u,20*log(abs(G2)),'LineWidth',2);
axis([-4 4 -200 0]);
xlabel('u'); 
ylabel('|G(u)|'); 
title('Far-Field Magnitude of a Cosine Function');

subplot(2,3,6); 
plot(u,20*log(abs(G3)),'LineWidth',2);
axis([-4 4 -200 0]);
xlabel('u'); 
ylabel('|G(u)|'); 
title('Far-Field Magnitude of a Triangular Function');
```

Comment: I'd suggest first you create a matlab function file that computes your function given some input arguments. Then, create a callback function in another file for your slider. Lastly, your callback will need to have the plot handles in order to update them. Try getting it to work with only one plot first, then it should be easy to make them all work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to create a simple GUI with three plots and a slider. Check [this MathWorks site](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_guis/introduction-to-guide.html) for an introduction to creating GUIs with GUIDE. I think you will find some examples of what you are trying to do.